# OpenIddict in abp framework - deploy in containerized environment (k8s)

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, reverse-proxy, abp, openiddict

abp version 6.0, tiered (.Web, .HttpApi.Host, .AuthServer), MVC.

The following messages appear in .AuthServer.

Client validation failed because 'https://webpage_url/signin-oidc' was not a valid redirect_uri for AppName_Web.
The authorization request was rejected because the redirect_uri was invalid: 'https://webpage_url/signin-oidc'.

How to properly set appsettings.json in .Web, .HttpApi.Host, .Web and .DbMigrator projects for deployment into containerized environments?
Where should be set internal (k8s) url address for auth server and when outer url (which is accessible via internet).

Url https://webpage_url/signin-oidc in the log is outer address (which is accessible via internet).

changing appsettings.json

Answer (score 0):

> Client validation failed because 'https://webpage_url/signin-oidc' was
> not a valid redirect_uri for AppName_Web. The authorization request
> was rejected because the redirect_uri was invalid:
> 'https://webpage_url/signin-oidc'.

Probably your redirect uri is not seeded, You can check your database if the redirect uri is added correctly for that client (application).

> How to properly set appsettings.json in .Web, .HttpApi.Host, .Web and
> .DbMigrator projects for deployment into containerized environments?
> Where should be set internal (k8s) url address for auth server and
> when outer url (which is accessible via internet).
>
> Url https://webpage_url/signin-oidc in the log is outer address (which
> is accessible via internet).

You **don't change the redirect uri** based on your deployment environment. It should point to a valid reachable endpoint that the openid-provider redirects to after signin.

As far as I understand, apart from normal login flow, you are having problems when interacting to openid-provider in isolated network (k8s, docker).

Since you have auth-server on real domain endpoint (like https://my-authserver.com), you are getting error from containers that tries to reach to domain (https://my-authserver.com/.well-known/openid-configuration) and you receive SSL error or not found error.

So you want internal requests done to the internal container (like http://my-auth-container/.well-known/openid-configuration) while user interacted login/logout should be done using the public domain name (https://my-authserver.com).

Instead of changing the public issuer, you can add **OpenIdConnectOptions** based on your deployment to configure `MetadataAddress` as:

```cs
context.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>("oidc", options =>
{
    options.MetadataAddress = configuration["AuthServer:MetaAddress"].EnsureEndsWith('/') +
                              ".well-known/openid-configuration";

    var previousOnRedirectToIdentityProvider = options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider;
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async ctx =>
    {
        // Intercept the redirection so the browser navigates to the right URL in your host
        ctx.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"].EnsureEndsWith('/') +
                                            "connect/authorize";

        if (previousOnRedirectToIdentityProvider != null)
        {
            await previousOnRedirectToIdentityProvider(ctx);
        }
    };

var previousOnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut =
    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut;

options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async ctx =>
{
    // Intercept the redirection for signout so the browser navigates to the right URL in your host
    ctx.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = configuration["AuthServer:Authority"].EnsureEndsWith('/') +
                                        "connect/endsession";

    if (previousOnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut != null)
    {
        await previousOnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut(ctx);
    }
};
```

This way, login/logout requests will be redirected to the `configuration["AuthServer:Authority"]` which should be a public domain (like https://my-authserver.com) and the internal requests will be redirected to the `configuration["AuthServer:MetaAddress"]` which should be an internal service (like http://my-auth-container)

For more details, check out:

- [eShopOnAbp Public-Web application configuration](https://github.com/abpframework/eShopOnAbp/blob/03833975a1cb3b3810ef0303589f48c1a329ac2d/apps/public-web/src/EShopOnAbp.PublicWeb/EShopOnAbpPublicWebModule.cs#L202-L235)
- [eShopOnAbp Azure deployment configuration](https://github.com/abpframework/eShopOnAbp/blob/main/etc/k8s/eshoponabp/values.azure.yaml#L42-L50)

Comment: Thank you @gterdem, we'll try this way.
In the case of tiered MVC project, this "AuthServer:Authority", "AuthServer:IsContainerizedOnLocalhost" (set to true) and "AuthServer:MetaAddress" should be set only in .Web project or also in .HttpApi.Host and .DbMigrator?

Comment: Db Migrator has nothing to do with openid connect options and http.api.host is stateless. I mean you won't be `logging in` from http.api.host. So no, only valid for MVC/Blazor-Server.